# Vuejs how to set on click function to semantic UI's close function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, semantic-ui

How do would I call semanticUI's function to close and fade message on icon click?

https://semantic-ui.com/collections/message.html#dismissable-block has a jQuery call (?) but Im not sure how to a similar thing in vue. Could someone explain what it is doing anyways? I know you are passing a function to do on click but what is $('.message .close') and $(this) in the function?

```
<i class="close icon" @click=???? >

$('.message .close')
  .on('click', function() {
    $(this)
      .closest('.message')
      .transition('fade')
    ;
  })
;
```

Comment: `$('.message .close')` is searching the html for an element with the class `close` that is inside an element with the class `message`,  probably a close button.  `$(this)` is referring to that element it found.

Comment: @StevenB. So it'll apply the on click function for all elements that fall in to the category like `<div class="... message"> <button> ..."` if button has a close class/attribute?

Comment: don't use jQuery with vue, it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

$('.message .close') is a jQuery class selector which will select the .message and .close class from your html elements $(this) will be the dom element it finds, you can use this code including the cdn in your html along with the cdn for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I should really look up documentation before posting this. Thanks for clearing things up, I was confused with difference between css classes vs function calls. Using the transition wrapper and v-if did the job.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components